# looping through php array

Tags: php

Can someone explain the logic behind this for loop... I just don't get it on how it goes into the next element, that `$from[$i]`, what is it doing?

```
$start = 2;

$path = array();
for (; $i != $start; $i = $from[$i])
         $path[] = $i;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very clearly written.  I assume `$i` and `$start` are previously initialized.

Basically, there is no for loop initialization.  It continues until `$i` equals `$start`.  In the body, `$i` is appended to the `$path` array.  Before going to the next iteration, `$i` is set to the value of the `$i` key in `$from`.

So if the array looked like:

```
$from = array('foo'=>'bar', 'bar'=>'baz', 'baz'=>'goo');
```

and `$i` are `$start` are 'foo' and 'goo' respectively, `$path` will end up:

```
array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

If `$start` is unreachable, it will loop forever.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing $from is an array that maps what the next $i should be based on a given $i.

So for each iteration, $i is assigned the value in $from at index $i.

(eg. if $i is 5 and $from[5] is 4, then the next value for $i is 4)

And it stops when it reaches the value $start.

Would need to know a bit more about what's in $from to help you further.